# Installshield Automation is failing while running vbscript with error unable to create object

Tags: vbscript, installshield

I am using Installshield 2013 SP1 SAB(stand alone build). I am trying to change the product codes, strings and properties with help of following VBSCRIPT. But my VBScript is failing at the following code with error: "Unable to CreateObject with IS automation interface"

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oISM = CreateObject("IswiAuto20.ISWiProject")
if Err.Number <> 0 Then
 Wscript.Echo "Unable to CreateObject with IS automation interface" & vbNewLine
 Wscript.Quit Err.Number
End If
```

I have registered **IswiAutomation20.dll** manually, but even that does not solve my issue. I am using a 32-bit build server.

Tagging installshield gurus as they are the ones who can help. VBScript gurus can help me if I am wrong in the script.

Comment: Verifying registration and making sure you were a 32bit process is all that comes to the top of my mind.

Comment: I am using a 32 bit processor Chris. Registration and all are fine. No idea what am I missing

Comment: I was running it on a 64-bit machine, but launching from the SysWOW64 folder. I had the same problem, and changing the 'sw' to 'SW' in the namespace fixed it. (See user1411212's answer below). Seeing as how that fixed my problem, I don't know why it's wrong in the InstallShield documentation.
http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm

Answer (score 1):

could be the case of the IswiAuto20 namespace.  Try I**SW**iAuto20 instead of "IswiAuto20". Rob

Comment: That was my problem, and changing the case fixed it. How come it's wrong on this page?
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/AutoStringTables.htm